# How to load phpseclib in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpseclib

As per title, has anyone achieved this? What are the best practices on including this library into codeigniter (v2.1.2) ?

I know it can be done by simply using include/require statements like any other PHP application, however as this project will be handed over to multiple devs once complete, I want to ensure it's built correctly using the design patterns the CI dev intended.

I've tried the following in a test controller

```
public function index(){

    $this->load->library('phpseclib0.3.0/Net/SFTP');

}
```

However I'm greeted with:

> Non-existent class: SFTP

phpseclib taken from [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `$this->load->library` method is for libraries that already exist within codeigniter.

You could create a wrapper for the PHPSecLib class, however what's probably easiest at the moment is to simply include it.

1. Download the source code fromm phpseclib's page.
2. Upload it to the /application/third_party folder
3. include the file.

   `include(APPPATH . '/third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');`
4. Create an instance of class your wanting to use.

Comment: This works great, depending on your setup, I had to add `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'third_party/phpseclib');` as shown in their documentation because Net/SSH2.php does some includes of its own that didn't work without phpseclib in the path.