# phpseclib giving no compatible server or client encryption algorithms found in

Tags: ssh, include-path, phpseclib

Hi All I appreciate that this question has been asked [Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641948/notice-no-compatible-server-to-client-encryption-algorithms-found-in) but the suggestions and answers provided have not solved my scenario and did not in any way go into depth about this issue and explain how the 'stream_resolve_include_path()' works, restarting apache did not fix my issue nor did any include path instructions i tried.

I do believe my issue is path related (maybe include path or maybe due to my directory structure but I'm unsure on how to fix.

I'm trying to connect to a remote server via phpseclib and when i include the files in a subdirectory to the document root it works but my script running in the root throws the error in my question.

phpseclib is running from the root and thus i have a directory structure as follows:

docroot (where the file calling the script fails)

- classes (this is the folder where my call is completed successfully)
- Crypt (the folder phpseclib has its encrytion algorithms in)
- File (phpseclib folder)
- Math (phpseclib folder)
- Net  (where the ssh2 file for phpseclib is located)
- Service (phpseclib folder)

a simplified version of my working file in classes is as follows:

```
<?php
set_include_path( '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include_once ('Net/SSH2.php');
public function updatessh($sshId, $sshAddress, $sshUserName, $sshPassword, $port = 22) {
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($sshAddress, $port);
    if (!ssh->login($sshUserName, $sshPassword)) {
        // Login failed
        ... code for failure
    } else {
        // Login success
        ... code for success
    }
```

this works fine, i login via ssh and can deal with the request.

My non working code snippet in the docroot is almost identical as follows:

```
<?php
set_include_path(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include_once ('Net/SSH2.php');
public function updatessh($sshId, $sshAddress, $sshUserName, $sshPassword, $port = 22) {
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($sshAddress, $port);
    if (!ssh->login($sshUserName, $sshPassword)) {
        // Login failed
        ... code for failure
    } else {
        // Login success
        ... code for success
    }
```

All parameters being passed into these functions are correct and verified numerous times trying to resolve this.

I have tried the same include path as the working example, appending $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOt'] doesn't work and not having the include fails too.

I'm at a loss, must be missing something here, the file after it is included then calls its own includes to get the Crypt folder right, surely that would be the same no?

the version of phpseclib is 0.3.something, I tried also with version 1 (which uses namespaces but had no success at all with that and as this was kind of working reverted to a non namespace version for this project.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

including the following on top worked for me:
`set_include_path(getcwd());`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. You saved 2 hours of mine.

Answer (score 0):

> set_include_path(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

This is nonsense. You've said that the both the phpseclib code and your code sit within the document root. I will assume that the document root is a sub-directory within the the filesystem, e.g. '/var/www/html' rather than '/', but the latter is exactly what you have specified as the location of the phpseclib files.

If the change the line above to:

```
set_include_path('.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

It should result in the same behaviour as the script which you say works, but this is not a good solution.

- there is no clear separation between your code and that of phpseclib
- you are breaking the default include path configured on your system

You first need to decide if you consider phpseclib an embedded part of your application or a part of the platform your application sits on. In the case of the former, you should have a single directory containing the phpseclib dirs within your project directory. In the second case, phpseclib should sit in single directory outwith your project.

Ideally, you should keep as much code as possible outside the document root to reduce the attack surface. In the case where you want to build a portable application which is simple to deploy, embedding the library makes this impossible - PHP does not have any means to indicate where code should be deployed to. However the latter approach described above allows for a consistent model for managing (and re-using) third party components on your system.

Placing the component elsewhere means that you can include the files with a static include path. Embedding the component means that you need to determine the include path dynamically. If you go down the embedded root then establish a datum directory (typically the base directory for the project) from which you can locate any additional resources you need.

Lastly, don't replace the include path in your scripts - add to it. Note that the order in which you add entries to the path is singificant (the list is searched from left to right) e.g.

```
$ipath=ini_get('include_path');
switch (DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR) {
   case '/':
      set_include_path(PROJECT_BASE . "/include" 
              . (strlen($ipath) ? ":$ipath" : ""));
      break;
   case '\\':
       set_include_path(PROJECT_BASE . "/include"
              . (strlen($ipath) ? ";$ipath" : ""));
       break;
   default:
       trigger_error("Unable to resolve system semantics", E_USER_ERROR);
       exit -1;
}
include_once ('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');
```

Comment: Ok so i got a new copy of 0.3.6 and put it in the root under phpseclib and have the include as follows set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib'); (right out the manual) where is the best place to put this? if i use an autoloader will it rebuild the include or keep adding until it crashes? I presume the former ie include it once?

Comment: 0.3.6? Why are you using such an old version of phpseclib? The latest version is 1.0.1. 0.3.6 was released almost two years ago. Also, typically, autoloaders do not modify the `include_path`.

Comment: @Craig: `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib'); ` is nearly as silly as what you started with. Please read the docs, your INI file and my response above, then fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was this:

> This works great, depending on your setup, I had to add
>   `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH .
>   'third_party/phpseclib');` as shown in their documentation because
>   Net/SSH2.php does some includes of its own that didn't work without
>   phpseclib in the path.

[How to load phpseclib in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950934/how-to-load-phpseclib-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error raise bcoz of file scopes.
Place your business logic code(php file) inside Project_Name/phpseclib folder and try.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on the previous answers, the reason this happens, is because encryption algorithms are loaded using code along the lines of:

```
if (class_exists('\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael') === false) {
        $encryption_algorithms = array_diff(
            $encryption_algorithms,
            array('aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc')
        );
}
```

So if your code loads phpseclib in a non-standard way, the classes containing the algorithms won't be loaded, the SSH2 object will assume it has no encryption algorithms and you'll get the error.

You may find you can load algorithms directly if required e.g :

```
require 'vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an oddball situation but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

I was working on some legacy code that produced this same error message.  When I dug into it, the client did have a group of algorithms - but they were all older than what the server had.  The system was using phpseclib version 1.  Upgrading to phpseclib version 3 (along with the tweaks that are required for the code) fixed the issue.