# SFTP in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sftp

I had some problems with upload the image from local server to remote server by using SFTP.
I prefer to use the phpseclib, but I don't know how to include the phpseclib in my Codeigniter. Can someone show me the steps? Thanks much.

Comment: reference link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950934/how-to-load-phpseclib-in-codeigniter]

Comment: @M.Hemant step 3 include the file, is include in the .htaccess file?